# MySQL Query Causing Deadlocks

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am dealing with a query that is causing some deadlocks, I believe because it's trying to SELECT from the same table it's updating. Regardless, this is a terribly clumsy way of doing this and I'd like to find a better way.

One obvious solution here is to pull the SELECT out into a separate query, but I'm hoping one of you SQL ninjas out there has a suggestion for a more elegant solution that could get this done in a single query with much less overhead.

```
SET @update_id := 0; 
UPDATE msgstream 
SET     retryCount = retryCount + 1, 
    retryTime = TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND,?,NOW(3)), 
    messageid = (SELECT @update_id := messageid) 
WHERE receiver = ? 
AND isDelivered = 0 
AND retryCount < 10 
AND retryTime < NOW(3)  
AND (
    SELECT m.counter 
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(messageid) AS counter 
        FROM msgstream 
            WHERE receiver = ? 
            AND isDelivered = 0 
            AND retryCount < 10 
            AND retryTime > NOW(3)
    ) AS m 
) = 0 
ORDER BY messageid LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Why do you need the sub-query ?

Comment: A deadlock (if you really mean a deadlock, and not just "the query is taking very long") is caused by at least two different sessions/transactions that require the same resources, but in order that unfortunately made them block each other. It cannot be caused by a single query, no matter how many subqueries you use.

Comment: It's definitely a deadlock. It's showing up in the logs. If it cannot be caused by a single query, no matter how many SELECT statements it contains, then it's probably something in the number of times this query is called (I'm working on that too). 

As for why we need the subquery, excellent question... The best I can come up with here is that we want to make sure no other message to `receiver` is coming up with `retryTime > NOW(3)`. The problem is that this is a pretty critical part of the app, so I don't want to change it too drastically because I'm not 100% sure why it was done this way.